# Best practice to make custom user authentication form in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication

I want to implement the user authentication and login page in ASP.NET, I want to make it highly secure, its a vast field and i didnt find any appropriate answer from the net search. Please, if anyone knows, refer me a best example for its implementation handling sessions, encryption and everything else that is need for a high security(which is my major concern) and prevention from Bots. I ve already implemented simple user authentication insertion deletion and login with simple SQL queries via stored procedures yet m sure its not enough.

Thanks
MGD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into this :

1. [ASP.NET 2.0 Membership and Roles Tutorial Series](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/07/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-Roles-Tutorial-Series.aspx)
2. [Security Basics and ASP.NET Support (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/security-basics-and-asp-net-support-cs)

Comment: Thanks Muhammad :) Lemme try it!!